# Dependency Injector Container in PHP

Tags: php, object-oriented, dependency-injection

I am practicing the SOLID principles and my first step was taking a dive into dependency injection(DI), so I created a class, a container for all DIs. It works, but I'm just not entirely sure if this is how I should go about doing it, although to me it seems fine.

```
interface ContainerInterface
{
    public function set($name, callable $value);
    public function get($name);
}

class DI implements ContainerInterface
{

    protected $services;


    public function set($name, callable $value)
    {
        $this->services[$name] = $value();
    }

    public function get($name)
    {
        return $this->services[$name];
    }

}
```

That covers the DI class, now I'll set an example of how I could use it:

```
$di = new DI();

$di->set('database', function() {
    return new Database();
});

$di->set('pagination', function() use ($di) {
    return new Pagination(DatabaseInterface $di->get('database'));
});

$application = new Application(ContainerInterface $di);
```

In the last line, I just injected the container and now I can access all the DIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Why not write anonymous functions in form of `function($container) { ... }` to allow your container to inject itself into function scope vs. having to use `function () use ($di) { ... }`?  This would allow wider compatibility to other forms of callables besides anonymous functions (for example, objects implementing `__invoke()` and other named functions/closures).
- Alternately, if you truly want to narrow the type of callable functions that can be passed to `set()`, you might consider type-hinting against `Closure` class, which is what PHP in fact uses to represent a "function" created using closure syntax.
- Why are you invoking the callable on `set()` and not on `get()`? This means you are pre-instantiating every dependency even if it is not needed for a particular code path. This kind of limits your framework to only allowing singleton-like behavior.  You could not pass a factory provider in one of your methods.  Perhaps it would be useful to have flag on `set()` if you want to implement singleton-like behavior, either by calling immediately or by storing information in separate arrays for "services" vs. single objects.
- Consider explicitly instantiating your services property to empty array `protected $services = []` such that IDE's (and readers) can infer type (that is if you are not going to use Doc blocks).
- You might consider better enforcing/validating the `$name` parameter.  Right now, I could pass it pretty much anything, making your container fragile to outside input. If using PHP 7+, you should type-hint for `string`.
- Is `DI` really a good class name? `DIContainer` perhaps?
- Should you throw an exception if `get()` is called and key doesn't exist? I would guess that this would not be an expected condition in a well-written application and failing loudly in such a case will hopefully make it obvious to a developer that they have a problem in their code.
- Is it OK that `set()` can overwrite existing item in the container?  You might consider preventing this in favor of needing an explicit `unset()` method to remove an item from the container.  This might suggest the need for a `has()` method.

For example:

```
public function has($name) {
    return array_key_exists($name, $this->services);
}

public function set($name, callable $value) {
    if($this->has($name)) {
        throw new Exception('...');
    }
    ...
}

public function get($name) {
    if(!$this->has($name)) {
        throw new Exception('...');
    }
    ...
}

public function unset($name) {
    unset($this->services[$name]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight on how I should actually setup a DIContainer. Your input has greatly widened my sight to how a DIC works. You pointed out a couple things I didn't even think of!!!